# Translation update successful but apparently not

Tags: updates, translation, automatic-updates

I was updating my multi site installation just minutes ago to WordPress 4.0. The dashboard keeps notifying me, of an available translation update. I updated it as well and it gave me a success message. When reloading the update page, it is still there for update. The status never changes. There will be the one translation update available forever.

Anyone else has this problem?

Comment: And then after a few hours, the notification went away like magic. Strange behaviour, however.